# Passing variable to URL and displaying it - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have {{contact.email}} that I have to pass in to URL and then display it in input field of form. 
It will be trigger by clicking on link.

```
var email= {{contact.email}};

<a href="https://{{contact.image}}" onclick="location.href=this.href+'?key='+email;return false;">
```

I think I'm missing something but don't know what.

And after I pass it to URL I would like to display it here:

```
<input id="id_username_email" maxlength="250" name="username_email" type="text">
```

Comment: What template engine are you using? Also, I strongly suggest not to print user input from QUERY_STRING directly into your html, you create a possibility of XSS attack.

Comment: What is the problem? Is the link not working or what?

Comment: well link is working I guess because I can see data that I'm sending (which is also not good) but it's not being displayed in input at all.

Comment: As you are saying the link is working, Give the code you are using to display the text in input field.

Comment: @VaTz88 can you give me some suggestions? :)

Comment: You can do it with javascript. Use `window.location.href` to get the link and then extract the text from it and add it to the input field.

Comment: @VaTz88 can you write it as code example due to what I posted up?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass javascript variable inside onclick like that.

Instead I suggest you do this

```
<a href="https://{{contact.image}}" onclick="location.href=this.href+'?key={{contact.email}}';return false;">
```

You also need to write the JS to set the value onload of this page. I hope you have written that part too.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to do something like this. Following code will extract the email from the url and add it to the field.

```js
var url = "http://example.com?key=example@example.com"; // say for example
var email = "";
email = url.split("=")[1]; // will extract email
// use following in actual code
// email = window.location.href.split("=")[1];
var emailField = document.getElementById("id_username_email");
emailField.value = email;
```

```html
<form>
  <input id="id_username_email" maxlength="250" name="username_email" type="text">
</form>
```